# Arduino based quadcopter flipping problem

Tags: quadcopter

I have built an Arduino DUE based quadcopter and I am using HC-12 as a transmitter and receiver between my laptop and the quadcopter. What am I doing is just send a speed value from my laptop and apply that value to all the quadcopter motors wirelessly.
The problem is my quadcopter is flipping while trying to go up. Watch this video [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/44475ig23nxshg8/Video%202018-10-28%20at%207.14.52%20PM.mp4?dl=0) to get an idea of what I mean. I had tried to make the quadcopter balanced and I got the same problem. By the way, I tried to change the motors and tried many ways to balance it and to make the center of gravity in the center of the quadcopter but I faced the same problem of flipping. 
I need to make the quadcopter go up normally without control and flipping just by giving the value of the motors speed from the laptop without RC.

**Edit**: Now I rebuilt it and recalibrated the ESCs after that, I got this [result](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wort2r2zb8t3eu1/VID.mp4?dl=0). My quadcopter seems to be hovering from 3 sides and the last one can't hover for the same speed. I tried to increase the speed of that motor and change the motor but I got no difference.

Comment: Are you using any feedback control, something like PID, and if so did you also tune them?

Comment: you have to realize that the flipping problem has nothing to do with the center of gravity of the quadcopter ..... it has everything to do with the amount of power being fed to the rotors ..... you require a feedback loop that controls the distribution of power to the four rotors

Comment: No, I am not using any controller in this part of my work, not even PID.

Comment: I have checked the power distribution but everything seems to be normal.

Comment: Very sorry I changed the link and now it is working @Szczepan

Comment: this design is not meant to fly open loop ...

Comment: @N.Staub I understand that and I have a complete control algorithm for the altitude but the problem is the balancing of the quadcopter while trying to go up from the ground.

Comment: you have an underactuated system you need to actively stabilize it, even the dimensions which are not relevant for your application ... You can not assume simulation wolrd of perfectly aligned and balanced design ... You need a low level PD loop on orientation so that your orientation is regulated to hover. Look at any paper on quadrotor control there most often two nested PD on for position one for orientation ...

Answer (score 1):

Quadrocopter is nowhere near to normal RC airplane, where balancing can help a lot with stability. You'll need to utilize *at least* [PID controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PID_controller) to keep your multirotor steady.

I guess you don't have much experience with quadrotors whatsoever, therefore I'd suggest you to use an integrated flight controller, i.e. [this one](https://hobbyking.com/en_us/rjx-sp-racing-f3-flight-controller-acro.html). Mind that, when building such device, you will surely need much more knowledge and experience in electronics and software engineering to get satisfying flight results.

Comment: Thank you for your answer
My problem now is that I am working only on the altitude of the quadcopter. I have designed a controller and its response seems to be good but it can't handle the tilting of the quadcopter because its purpose is just for the altitude.
I implemented this quadcopter first by using APM 2.6 flight controller and RC FS-I6, I controlled it by the RC and everything was good but in my project, I should design my own controller for this reason I change the controller.
My purpose of what am I doing is just to make the quadcopter hover normally and all at the same level.

Comment: @AwsAbdulSalam you can't only use a controller for altitude, you also need attitude control.

Comment: @fibonatic but my work purpose now is just to make the quadcopter go up and down without any small tilting in it and without using attitude control

Comment: @AwsAbdulSalam You can't because any small perturbation, even if the drone is perfectly ballanced, will cause the thrust to also point partially in a horizontal direction and the drone will start accelerating sideways.

Comment: @fibonatic what if I designed and implemented my own frame and perfectly balanced it, will I face the same problem.

Comment: Yes, you **will** face the same problem. [Please read this article about PID in multicopters](https://oscarliang.com/quadcopter-pid-explained-tuning/), hopefully you'll find that descriptive and helpful.

Comment: @Szczepan Thank you I will read it carefully and wish it will help me.

Comment: @fibonatic - More than just accelerating sideways, if there is a horizontal component to thrust then you'll get a **torque** and the drone will begin to accelerate in a spiral/corkscrew.

Comment: @AwsAbdulSalam - You're asking about manually balancing the frame, but the control problem is essentially an inverted pendulum problem, and you're saying you want to control the inverted pendulum by balancing the pendulum, not by controlling it. It doesn't matter how perfectly you make the pendulum, it is **inherently unstable** and **will** flip/rotate eventually. As fibonatic mentioned, any perturbation will start the flipping process, including things as minor as wire resistances to the motors, motor placement, motor and rotor balancing, wind, and reflected rotor wash from walls, etc.